# Apps can't see the light sensor but automatic brightness works anyway?

Tags: hardware, screen-brightness, backlight, sony-xperia-neo-v

I don't have a toggle for automatic brightness in my phone's settings menu and I cannot install apps like [Lux Auto Brightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux.free&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnZpdG8ubHV4LmZyZWUiXQ..) that depend on the light sensor. I can, however, turn automatic brightness on using Widgetsoid and it works fine. Why do all the apps think I don't have a light sensor and how can I fix this?

Since I have installed Cyanogenmod, I can now install Lux. However it always sees a brightness of -1 Lux.

Comment: Could you write what device you have?

Comment: Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo V.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem with Lux, always light reported -1, which I don't know it's a problem either from phone, sensor, Android, or Lux itself! BTW, I solved it by using front camera instead of light sensor. here is how:

- go to Lux settings
- click on Sample Collection
- click on Light reading modes
- select Camera instead of Light sensor
- select Front camera (it's obvious that its better than rear camera for this purpose)
- Now, from main screen of settings, click on Modify Linked Samples
- from top, click on Luma (this app uses Lux for sensor readings and Luma for camera readings)
- then you can see app reads ambient light value from camera and displays at top.
- Now the app should do its job, but you may want to check other settings to match your preferences.

good luck

Comment: I figured that the app would work with the camera but this is only supported by the paid version.